# R shiny : Color plot using ggplot

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a plot in R shiny app based on usr input. My filtering of data is a bit complicated and I am unsure fow to pass it to "fill" in ggplot. Below is my code:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$name)
    req(input$type)
    fp %>%
      dplyr::filter(
        name %in% input$name,
        if_any(
          matches(
            str_c('status___', tolower(input$type))), ~
                 .x ==2),
        on_date >= input$Dates[1] &
          off_date <= input$Dates[2]
        ) %>%
      group_by(country) %>%
      summarize(All = n(), .groups = "drop")

  })

##Plot
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data(), aes( y = All, x = country)) #this is wehere I want to use fill to color the plot by "type"
    g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass reactive input as variables in the ggplot `aes()` you need to use `aes_string()`.

Try this ggplot code :

```
geom_bar(data = data(),
         aes_string(y = "All",
                    x = "country",
                    fill = input$type), 
         stat = "sum")
```

Comment: I get an error `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

Comment: Just edited. Try again

Comment: I get a new error "More than one expression parsed"

Comment: try  `g + geom_bar(stat = "sum", fill = .data[[input$type]] )`

Comment: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): fill

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `data()` does **not** contain a column called `type`. You can verify that, by including a `dataTableOutput` element to your `UI` and render `data` to that. `summarize` will include only the grouping variables (`country`  in your case)  and the aggregated column (`All`).

Maybe you can provide a full [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) then we cna help better.